# Python - Max index value of a string

Tags: python, string, indexing

I have a list of strings and i would like to extract : "000000_5.612230" of :

```
A = '/calibration/test_min000000_5.612230.jpeg'
```

As the size of the strings could evolve, I try with monitoring the position of "n" of "min". I try to get the good index with :

```
print sorted(A, key=len).index('n')
```

But i got "11" which corresponds to the "n" of "calibration". I would like to know how to get the maximum index value of the string?

Comment: What do you think `sorted(A, key=len)` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is difficult to answer since you don't specify what part of the filename remains constant and what is subject to change. is it always a jpeg? is the number always the last part? is it always preceded with '_min' ?

in any case, i would suggest using a regex instead:

```
import re

A = '/calibration/test_min000000_5.612230.jpeg'
p = re.compile('.*min([_\d\.]*)\.jpeg')
value = p.search(A).group(1)
print value
```

output :

```
000000_5.612230
```

note that this snippet assumes that a match is always found, if the filename doesn't contain the pattern then `p.search(...)` will return `None` and an exception will be raised, you'll check for that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re` module and the regex to do that, for example:

```
import re

A = '/calibration/test_min000000_5.612230.jpeg'
text = re.findall('\d.*\d', A)
```

At now, `text` is a list. If you print it the output will be like this: `['000000_5.612230']`

So if you want to extract it, just do this or use `for`:

```
import re

A = '/calibration/test_min000000_5.612230.jpeg'
text = re.findall('\d.*\d', A)

print text[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

String slicing seems like a good solution for this

```
>>> A = '/calibration/test_min000000_5.612230.jpeg'
>>> start = A.index('min') + len('min')
>>> end = A.index('.jpeg')
>>> A[start:end]
'000000_5.612230'
```

Avoids having to import re

Comment: You probably want the reverse index, [**`rindex`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex) to find the last `min` and the last `.jpeg`, although the last `.jpeg` will always be at `-5`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (if extension is always '.jpeg'):

```
A.split('test_min')[1][:-5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is regular at the end, you can use negative indices to [slice the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation):

```
>>> a = '/calibration/test_min000000_5.612230.jpeg'
>>> a[-20:-5]
'000000_5.612230'
```

Comment: It seems from your question that the start is not regular but the end is. So you always have the 15 characters you want followed by `.jpeg`.